# MissingResourceException - Bundle not found during maven integration-test phase

Tags: maven

I'm building a multilingual website using maven.

Properties file are stored in /src/main/resources

The war generated by maven during the building phase contains the *.properties files in WEB-INF/classes. If I deploy this war file to a production environment there is no MissingResourceException thrown.

So everything work fine except during Integration tests where there is this MissingResourceException. By the way integration tests are executed thanks to failsafe-maven-plugin.

So what's going wrong during the integration test phase ?

What is really strange is that I can load another property file (not for I18N purpose) during the integration tests. The only difference is instead of using  ResourceBundle.getBundle I use a FileReader.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem was "just" the baseName I used to get the bundle :

ResourceBundle.getBundle("/MyBundle");

instead of

ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyBundle");

Nevertheless, it is a strange behavior because the first line of code works well when the .war is deployed but not during the integration-tests. If anyone know why, I'm really interested by the answer !

Comment: I think you got it backwards... 

ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyBundle"); <--- works
ResourceBundle.getBundle("/MyBundle"); <--- doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

With FileReader one cannot set the character encoding. Better use `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "ISO-8859-1")`, which is explicit, OS independent. And where ISO-8859-1 is the standard encoding of properties (ugly).

Besides /src/test/resources also /src/main/resources should be found.

Did you check /target/classes?

Likely an error in the copying phase (prepare-resources, prepare-test-resources etc.).
Maybe a class-relative `getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath)`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To answer your questions : The I18N file is in /target/classes and I do not use something like getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath) I use ResourceBundle.getBundle("baseName"). What I don't understand is that we have the test phase (maven-surefire-plugin) then the packaging phase (maven-war-plugin) and after that the integration test phase (failsafe-maven-plugin) that should use the war file generated before (this war file that work in production) and if I check it the I18N files are in. Am I wrong on the maven process ?

Comment: Seems okay (to me); take a look in the `.m2` maven repository too; inspecting with 7zip/WinZip the war.

Comment: I have just checked the war in ~/.m2/repository and the I18N properties file are missing but the other properties files are there. We are on the right track ! I added the 18n files after so there is a problem with the update of that war in the ~/m2 folder. I just tried to do a mvn clean and increment the version in my pom.xml and restart the process but the exception is still there during the integration test and consequently the .war is not installed anymor in the ~/.m2/repository folder.

Comment: A hack would be to move the resource into another maven project. Maybe setting the verbosity -v on, might help tracing the problem. Also the test itself might specify things in its own way. - Sorry I am not much help remotely.

Comment: Ok I find what was wrong, I'll post the answer. Thanks a lot for your help.